# Convergence, find the mistake I made!

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I admit it: I am a student, and this is my homework. Still, I am at the end of my wits. I have tried solving it like this:

[image]

There is a mistake somewhere. I cannot find it. All I am asking is to give it a quick look. Please.

I am unsure about number 5. As far as i could determine it is zero. Therefore it diverges, right? Is this my mistake?

I am also unsure about number 7. In my opinion it diverges. What do you think?

Edit 1: Well. It seems i was correct about number 5 and 7 then. I got doubts about number 3. There is no sum sign. Does it diverge as i thought?

Edit 2: BIG THANKS for no downvotes :)

I am looking forward, to your help!

Best regards,
Max

Comment: A series diverges only when it sums to $\pm\infty$. So if you know it sums to a finite number, it must converge

Comment: Please, report *only* the parts that bother you, typing them in and showing your work.

Comment: How can i type them here?

Comment: I will do it :)

Comment: This is somewhat similar to your previous post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604212/convergence-find-my-mistake

Comment: Re: *How can i type them here?* For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer before someone beats me to it:

For number 5, if you consider what the sequence of results is, it oscillates between $0/1$ and $2/3$.  So, essentially this series is $0 + 2/3 + 0 + 2/3....$etc.  It diverges to infinity.  You might describe this method as an "nth-term test."

For number 7, first factor out an $n^\frac{1}{3}$ out of the denominator, so you have $\frac{n^3 +1}{(n^9 + 1)^\frac{1}{3} (n^\frac{1}{3})}$.  Toss out the $+ 1$ part of the numerator and denominator, they add hardly anything to the overall value of the fraction.  Now, the $n^3/(n^9)^\frac{1}{3}$ will become $n^3/n^3 =1$.  So we're left with $1/n^\frac{1}{3}$.  This diverges to infinity as well by p-Series test (p<1).

Comment: So it converges yes?

Comment: Sorry, meant that it diverges.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers you refer to correspond to the natural order, the general term is alternatively $0$ and $2/3$, hence the series diverges (the general term should tend to $0$).

For number 7, it is easily seen to diverge with the comparison test and equivalence:
$$n^3+1\sim_\infty n^3,\quad\sqrt[3]{n^{10}+n\mathstrut}\sim_\infty\frac{n^3}{n^{\tfrac{10}3}}=\frac1{n^{\tfrac13}},$$
which diverges.